# Thrust array of device_vectors to raw_pointer

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia, thrust

Using device_vector:

```
thrust::device_vector< int > iVec;
int* iArray = thrust::raw_pointer_cast( &iVec[0] );
```

but how can I do it if I have an array of device_vectors?

```
thrust::device_vector<int> iVec[10];
```

Ideally I would like to pass my array of device_vector to a 1D array to be handled on a CUDA kernel. Is it possible?

Comment: You understand that a `device_vector` is a C++ class in *host* memory? An array of `device_vector` is an array of C++ class instances, also in *host* memory. There is no raw device pointer because there is no device memory involved.

Comment: @talonmies: So,there is no way I can covert the array of device_vector to 1D host array?

Comment: An array of device vectors *is* already 1D host array. What is it that you are really trying to do?

Comment: I want to pass the array to a kernel so I can deal with it with all the elements in order, thinking that every array might have different length of the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, what you are really try to do is create an array of raw pointers from an array of `thrust::device_vectors`. You should be able to do this like so:

```
const int N = 10;
thrust::device_vector<int> iVec[N];

int * iRaw[N];
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    iRaw[i] = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(iVec[i].data());

int ** _iRaw;
size_t sz = sizeof(int *) * N;
cudaMalloc((void ***)&_iRaw, sz);
cudaMemcpy(_iRaw, iRaw, sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

[disclaimer: written in browser, never compiled, never tested, use at own risk]

In the above code snippet, `_iRaw` holds the raw pointers of each of the device vectors in `iVec`. You could pass that to a kernel if you really wanted to.